# From SQL Server to Oracle using Entity Framework with code-first Migrations

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I'm was told recently that in our current project we have to use Oracle instead of SQL Server.

I need some help to make it work. I've already installed Visual Studio ODTwithODAC but when I try to run the command `update-database` in the Package Manager Console, the following error is thrown:

> A null was returned after calling the 'get_ProviderFactory' method on a store provider instance of type 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection'. The store provider might not be functioning correctly.

I know that the problem is not the access to DB because I could connect to it via Server Explorer and I took the connection string from it.

My connection string goes like this:

```
<add name="LpssContext" 
     connectionString="SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.0.1.106)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)));uid=sys;pwd=sys;" 
     providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
```

Any ideas about what's wrong?

Does Oracle support code-first migrations?

Comment: I think your providerName should be something else than System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: `provider=System.Data.SqlClient`?

Comment: shouldn't be providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" ?

Comment: The provided connection string and message was updated. SqlClient won't work because this is Oracle. EntityClient didn't work

Comment: As far as I know Oracle doesn't support code-first: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2558851

Comment: Any workaround to suggest? What do you think it would be the best to do?

Comment: any final solution about it ? Can I use EF Code First using ODP.NET ? ODAC 12c not supports EF Code First.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's no support for CFM with Oracle connector.
There's a paid connector that support it though, http://blog.devart.com/entity-framework-code-first-migrations-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite.html

The other option is to change your db layer to DB First (with lots of work) manually, as I finally did